# Configure php mail() function on a Raspberry pi with PHP fpm

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I've a contact form (Contact Form 7) on my wordpress site which is hosted by my Raspberry Pi 2. I am using PHP fpm. Is there a built-in function to send mails in PHP fpm or do I need additional software like postfix?

Anyway, how should I configure it so the Raspberry Pi can send mails that are submitted by the contact form?

Comment: Why not use [`wp_mail`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) instead?